# Bind ObservableCollection to a Collection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I made a solution wich contains 4 projects, UI, BL, DAL and BO.

- UI : usercontrols, windows.
- BL : some logics, and a static class.
- Dal : a static class repository.
- BO : my objects ( Person, ...)

The first 3 projects have reference to BO project, and UI refer to BL and BL to DAL.
In BL project I have a **Collection**, and in my UI (in a ViewModel) I have an **ObservableCollection**, the problem is the binding between these 2 Collections, for example, when I want to add a person, I have to do like that :

```
BL.Persons.Add( new Person() { Name = "Paul"});
this.Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>(BL.Persons);
```

it works, but I'm not sure if it's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't re-create your `ObservableCollection` each time. It doesn't make sense in this situation because an `ObservableCollection` supposed to notify observers about the change. Of course this works because the `Persons` changes, but it's very inefficient with larger collections because it will act like every object has changed but in the reality only a new one added.

This is better for you:

```
var person = new Person() { Name = "Paul"};
BL.Persons.Add(person);
this.Persons.Add(person);
```

Btw I don't like this kind of Model/ViewModel mixing, it would be better if you only expose *viewmodels* to your *view*, much cleaner, but that's a different question.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the answer, and if you can tell me more about Model/ViewModel mixing ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be even better to make `BL.Persons` also an ObservableCollection and let `this.Persons` be the same instance? You would set `this.Persons = BL.Persons` once and now only have one collection instead of two.

Comment: yes it's a good idea Clemens, but if I change my UI to Winforms for example , I have to change my BL too, that's why I'm using basic collections in BL and DAL.

Comment: @DotNeter, `ObservableCollection` works for winforms also. Its just that in `WinForms` you have to rebind on `ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: @DotNeter you are exposing your model as if it were a viewmodel. You should create a person viewmodel where that viewmodel models the actual view. Your business entities aren't your viewmodels.

Comment: @DotNeter I do not agree with your statement about having to create a ViewModel always. I think there are some situations (such as read only grid showing only model data) in which it's ok to bind directly from the view to the model. Then, if the view requires more complexity (such as a CRUD view or editable grids with lots of validations or UI related logic) a ViewModel is required.

Comment: @HighCore I think **consistency** is a value it worth to do that minimal extra work even if the actual readonly grid is really really very simple. For playing around or putting things together quickly it's ok, but in real projects consistency is priceless.

Comment: @PeterPorfy I work in a project where the guy who defined the overall architecture of the application (long before I came here to change it all and implement MVVM) decided that because of "consistency", data access layers in the client (the classes that interact with the WCF services to retrieve data from the server) should only be accessed from the big main controller of the current section of the app, and not individual widgets, so you have, for example, an address widget that needs to retrieve zip codes and it does so by throwing an event that is catched and responded to by each controller

Comment: @PeterPorfy where there is an address, generating endless streams of copypasted code everywhere, and endless event handler chains. Forget consistency. Less code produces less bugs. Have the dev team adapt to that instead. fire idiots who winforms-it-all, hire real devs.

Comment: @HighCore I agree with you that overcomplicated architecture is bad but it seems you just saw a badly designed architecture. it has nothing to do with consistency. repeating yourself (copypaste) is always a bad habit regardless to the design choices made. good design and testing is what makes your application more stable. forget consistency? interesting idea but I don't buy it.